# AS3 Air for iOS How do I make double click program

Tags: flash, air

I know already that Double click event is not available for iOS(iPhone, iPad).
But for example google map or other drawing applications have function of double click to scale up.

I have found sample program at Web. But I cannot found the ActionScript3 program to implement double lick event for Air for iOS.
If you know that, please tell me.

My application need the three functions, MouseDrag, MouseGesture(scale up, down) and double click to scale up for image.

Answer (score 2):

I'm developing library for gesture recognition called [Gestouch](https://github.com/fljot/Gestouch). It will help you to detect double-tap, pan and scale(zoom). Just like this:

```
var doubleTap:TapGesture = new TapGesture(image);
doubleTap.numTapsRequired = 2;
doubleTap.addEventListener(TapGestureEvent.GESTURE_TAP, onDoubleTap);
...
private function onDoubleTap(event:TapGestureEvent):void
{
    // handle double tap!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't messed around too much with building iOS apps with Flash but I'd think Double_Click would be supported, just like CLICK would be. (in the touch world commonly referred to as "Tap" and "Double Tap").

On the object that you want to receive the event, you can try setting your `InteractiveObject.doubleClickEnabled = true;` [According to the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#doubleClickEnabled) it is `false` by default. Make sure `mouseEnabled = true` too.